# Convert IDataReader to SQLDataReader

Tags: c#, nunit, typemock

Is there a way to convert `IDataReader` object to `SqlDataReader` object? I am trying to break database dependency to one of API, by intercepting `SqlHelper` by with my own `IDataReader` (since I can't create a `SqlDataReader` object).

This is how my test case looks like (and evaluating TypeMock):

```
Isolate.Fake.StaticMethods(typeof(SqlHelper));
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(string.Empty, CommandType.StoredProcedure, string.Empty))
     .WillReturn(myDataGenerator.ToDataReader() as SqlDataReader);
```

This get compiled with no problem, but does not return any rows. When I debug I see that it does not have any rows at all. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit(1):**
Since conversion is not possible, is it possible to mock SqlDataReader.

Comment: You said - it compiles successfully then there may be another issue. Please post relevant code here.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't convert a `IDataReader` to a `SqlDataReader`.  `SqlDataReader` [is a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isa_%28computer_science%29) `IDataReader` - an `SqlDataReader` can be converted to an `IDataReader` not the otherway around.

Your real problem is that your code wasn't written to be testable.  Really `SqlHelper` should be an instance class is passed in and can be mocked and returns an `IDataReader`.  Or the method or methods that you are testing can be refactored so they don't rely on `SqlHelper` direclty and take `IDataReader`'s.

However if as I suspect you don't control this code, you can create your own DataReader that inherits from `SqlDataReader`.  All the `IDataReader` methods are virtual so you can override them your self.

Comment: You are right, I don't have control over that code. I can create my own DataReader, but that is not going to help the existing huge code base. It is like which one I do first? Write test cases for a legacy code, so I can refactor. Or refactor so I can write test cases for it. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: NOTE: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader can not be inherited. The helper class must implement IDataReader and wrap an instance of SqlDataReader. Also, IDataReader is in interface, not an abstract class. Therefore, all members of IDataReader must be implemented in the helper class.

Comment: You can: IDataReader reader = (some code to get result) SqlDataReader sDataReader = (SqlDataReader) reader;

Answer (score 0):

So your SqlHelper.ExecuteReader supposed to return a SqlDataReader?  Why don't you just have your SqlHelper.ExecuteReader use an IDataReader.

The answer by shf301 was just posted and is better written than mine, but exactly what you need to know.